# QT. Кнопки: save(save as), open(open as), project

Tags: qt

- 1 Вопрос(save as and save): Что бы сохранялось ясно и что бы при закрытие окна, если не было сохранен файл, то спрашивать("Уверены, что хотите закрыть файл?"). Также, если файл еще не был сохранен нигде, то при нажатие на "save" - оно открывало окно, в котором мы выбираем место сохранения и что бы запоминало ту папку, где мы сохранили. И главное - я хочу сохранять отдельные проекты(это в вопросе №3) и картинки, и что бы сохраняло область видимого окна.
- 2 Вопрос(open as and open): Что бы открывало файлы (проекты, которые в вопросе №3) и также запоминало последнюю папку, откуда открывали проект.
- 3 Вопрос(project): Как создать свой проект, что бы у него было свое расширение и что бы была иконка и что бы она открывалась только в моей программе?

Comment: Вы поясните, что за конопки и в чем у вас пролблема?? Если вы с IDE QtCreator разбиаретесь, тут отдно. Если вы что-то свое пишете тут другое. Конкретика нужна.

Comment: Мне нужны такие кнопки, что бы они выполняли те функции, которые я описал. И просто напишите, если знаете(пишу свое)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Надо держать в памяти флаг, отвечающий за состояние проекта. При закрытии окна проверять состояние флага и задавать вопрос. В Qt есть специальное [свойство](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowModified-prop) для интерфейсного уведомления пользователя о том, что файл изменен. Для сохранения в файл хранить путь к файлу проекта, при создании пустого проекта оставлять путь пустым. При сохранении проверять, если путь пустой, выдавать запрос на путь, куда сохранять.

2) Последнюю папку запоминать в основном окне программы и сохранять в конфиг/реестр при закрытии окна ([QSettings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html)), при старте, соответственно, считывать и давать как путь по умолчанию в `QFileDialog`.

3) Спроектировать свой формат файла, можно бинарный, можно текстовый, как вам удобнее (бинарный меньше и быстрее, текстовый проще отлаживать и можно редактировать любым текстовым редактором). При старте программы анализировать ключи запуска (`QCoreApplication::arguments()`), второй (с индексом 1) из них будет содержать путь к файлу проекта, который надо попытаться открыть.

---

У вас наверняка есть класс, реализующий проект. Если нет, его нужно сделать. В нем хранить все необходимые данные для расчетов, возможно в нем же хранить настройки визуализации. Там же хранить флаги измененности и пути, которые я описал выше. Реализовать методы `saveToFile(QString)` и `loadFromFile(QString)`, позволяющие сохранить/загрузить проект из файла.

Comment: Извините, но я начинающий. Мне не все понятно

Comment: Это нормально, все мы начинали, не умея ничего. Однако ваш вопрос содержит несколько отдельных пунктов и если отвечать на каждый, получится довольно большая статья. Попробуйте конкретизировать, что именно непонятно. Лучше конечно было разбить вопрос на несколько.

Comment: Ладно. Давайте вы мне пропишите весь первый ответ, другие пока что не надо. Они более менее понятны мне, попытаюсь разобраться. Но я прошу, перечитайте первый вопрос еще раз. Я просто хочу, что бы были проверки, о которых я написал выше

Comment: Вы точно уверены, что "давайте вы мне пропишите весь первый ответ" и "перечитайте первый вопрос еще раз" это правильный подход к людям, от которых вы рассчитываете получить помощь? Вам уже выше сказали, что в вашем вопросе не достает конкретики - какие картинки, какая область видимого окна? Добавил пояснение по реализации в ответ. Что-то более конкретное подсказать, не видя вашего кода и ваших попыток решить эту задачу, невозможно.

Comment: Я думаю вы знаете про **AdobePhotoshop**. Так вот, когда там создают виджет(или окно, как вам удобнее), то он появляется отдельно и при вносе в программу, он с ним стыкается и в нем есть область, в которой можно что-то делать. Вот я хочу узнать как такое сделать.

Comment: Это совершенно отдельный вопрос, никак не связанный с тем, что вы написали в этом вопросе. Задайте его отдельно, и вам ответят там.

Comment: Пожалуйста, извините. Просто я еще не сильно подрос и свои мысли плохо высказываю. А код я не смогу показать, так как удалил, потому что я дальше начал делать, то что знаю.